# how to perform statistical significant test to compare output values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

basically I have this dataframe:

```
baseline_data: userid|y_pred
                 12  |29
                 13  |35
                 14  |32 
                 15  |39
```

and I have created a model and got the age data: df

```
userid|age
12    |31
13    |37
14    |32
15    |36
```

how can I run a statistical significance test to check that this model performs significantly better than the baseline prediction ?

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-hypothesis-tests-in-python-cheat-sheet/ 
This article provides all kind of examples with code snippets for statistical testing in python

Answer (score 0):

Without validation dataset how can one conduct statistical analysis? For simulation/prediction models you need **two sets** of sample/observed data. One set will be used to **train** the model and another set will be used to **validate** the model predictions. Generally, the training and validation data set is split into an 80:20 ratio. So, you need to select your validation dataset size based on training dataset size.

Let's assume you have trained your model based on a training dataset of `d1` and you have another **validation dataset** **`d2`** for the userids that you have predicted using your models.

```
d2:

   userid  age
0      12   30
1      13   36
2      14   32
3      15   37
```

Now, you want to compare d2.age with your previous two models data. Let's assume other two dfs are m1 and m2 respectively.  they are `m1.y_pred` and `m2.age`.

```
import numpy as np
rmse_m1=np.sqrt(((m1.y_pred - d2.age) ** 2).mean())
rmse_m2=np.sqrt(((m2.age - d2.age) ** 2).mean())
rmse_m1:
1.224744871391589
rmse_m2:
0.8660254037844386
```

Now, lower values of **RMSE** indicate better fit. So, does your m2 model predictions are better? Well, though the second value of RMSE is smaller than the other; you can check if the difference is statistically significant to be able to say that one model is better than the other.

For more information read [Confidence interval of RMSE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78079/confidence-interval-of-rmse)